# Rails Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating a shop application in Rails 3.1 and I have Product and Category models.  The Category model has a name attribute which contains values such as Clothing, Arts and Crafts etc.

I'd like users to be able to access products filtered by category using this path www.example.com/products/clothing but I'm not sure how to set-up the routes.rb file to do that.  The tricky part is when it gets to category names with spaces in it (e.g. Arts and Crafts), is there a way to make it look like www.example.com/products/arts-and-crafts?

Thanks!

Comment: To solve the problem of category names with space you may want to use the [`permalink_fu`](https://github.com/technoweenie/permalink_fu) gem.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cover quite a lot of ground with one question.

Consider reading the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), specifically the part on resourceful routes.

Start off with using the simplest default routes, which will look like '/categories/123', make it work. Then come back and ask another question. :)